# Reporting job pages with advertisements

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

There are many company and job pages which seem to be offering services and advertising rather than introducing their companies.  For example [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/doorturkcelikkapi), there are many pages like this in my language (Persian).

I think it would be beneficial to place a report button on company pages not just company job listings.

Comment: You can report a job listing but I dont think there is a way to report a company page.  You have to email the SO team.

Comment: So with feature-request tag am i right here?

Comment: I don't know if it will be implemented I asked about this almost two years ago.

Comment: Are SO team see question's asked here? or here is just other community driven place?

Comment: No the team does in fact see and read and many times respond to the question.  My point is I asked this question already about two years ago and it was declined and I was told to email the SO team directly (there is a contact us link on the bottom of the page) for issues with companies.  I agree with you though I think this should in fact be implemented.

Comment: This is part of our 2017 roadmap. Don't have specifics yet but will update this post when I do.

Comment: I removed the [status-review] tag from this post because the Jobs product no longer exists.